# Can i establish a tcp/ip socket with a python server but a c++ client?

Tags: python, c++, sockets, tcp

I'm new to tcp/ip programming and I'm trying to establish a tcp/ip connection that sends a byte from my python server to a c++ client. Is this possible or does the client and server have to be written in the same programming language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tcp connection does not depend on programming language you could make connection between two processes one of them should be listen for another(server) and the other should send sync packet to request a connection(client). You could  implement  two mentioned components with every language programming.If you need more help let us know.